# Sieve of Eratosthenes NOT using boolean

Tags: java

Trying to write a sieve of eratosthenes program, when I run it it prints out

```
334,335,336,337,338,339,340,341,342,343,344,345,346,347,348,349,350,351,352,353,354,355,356,357,358,359,360,361,362,363,364,365,366,367,368,369,370,371,372,373,374,375,376,377,378,379,380,381,382,383,384,385,386,387,388,389,390,391,392,393,394,395,396,397,398,399,400,401,402,403,404,405,406,407,408,409,410,411,412,413,414,415,416,417,418,419,420,421,422,423,424,425,426,427,428,429,430,431,432,433,434,435,436,437,438,439,440,441,442,443,444,445,446,447,448,449,450,451,452,453,454,455,456,457,458,459,460,461,462,463,464,465,466,467,468,469,470,471,472,473,474,475,476,477,478,479,480,481,482,483,484,485,486,487,488,489,490,491,492,493,494,495,496,497,498,499,500,501,502,503,504,505,506,507,508,509,510,511,512,513,514,515,516,517,518,519,520,521,522,523,524,525,526,527,528,529,530,531,532,533,534,535,536,537,538,539,540,541,542,543,544,545,546,547,548,549,550,551,552,553,554,555,556,557,558,559,560,561,562,563,564,565,566,567,568,569,570,571,572,573,574,575,576,577,578,579,580,581,582,583,584,585,586,587,588,589,590,591,592,593,594,595,596,597,598,599,600,601,602,603,604,605,606,607,608,609,610,611,612,613,614,615,616,617,618,619,620,621,622,623,624,625,626,627,628,629,630,631,632,633,634,635,636,637,638,639,640,641,642,643,644,645,646,647,648,649,650,651,652,653,654,655,656,657,658,659,660,661,662,663,664,665,666,667,668,669,670,671,672,673,674,675,676,677,678,679,680,681,682,683,684,685,686,687,688,689,690,691,692,693,694,695,696,697,698,699,700,701,702,703,704,705,706,707,708,709,710,711,712,713,714,715,716,717,718,719,720,721,722,723,724,725,726,727,728,729,730,731,732,733,734,735,736,737,738,739,740,741,742,743,744,745,746,747,748,749,750,751,752,753,754,755,756,757,758,759,760,761,762,763,764,765,766,767,768,769,770,771,772,773,774,775,776,777,778,779,780,781,782,783,784,785,786,787,788,789,790,791,792,793,794,795,796,797,798,799,800,801,802,803,804,805,806,807,808,809,810,811,812,813,814,815,816,817,818,819,820,821,822,823,824,825,826,827,828,829,830,831,832,833,834,835,836,837,838,839,840,841,842,843,844,845,846,847,848,849,850,851,852,853,854,855,856,857,858,859,860,861,862,863,864,865,866,867,868,869,870,871,872,873,874,875,876,877,878,879,880,881,882,883,884,885,886,887,888,889,890,891,892,893,894,895,896,897,898,899,900,901,902,903,904,905,906,907,908,909,910,911,912,913,914,915,916,917,918,919,920,921,922,923,924,925,926,927,928,929,930,931,932,933,934,935,936,937,938,939,940,941,942,943,944,945,946,947,948,949,950,951,952,953,954,955,956,957,958,959,960,961,962,963,964,965,966,967,968,969,970,971,972,973,974,975,976,977,978,979,980,981,982,983,984,985,986,987,988,989,990,991,992,993,994,995,996,997,998,999
```

Could someone figure out how I can fix it.

```
public class Lab111 {
    public static void main(String [] args){

    int [] a = new int[1000];
    init(a); 
    findPrimes(a); 
    printPrimes(a); 
    }

    public static void init(int[] a){

        for (int i = 2; i < a.length; i++)
            if (a[i] == 0)
                a[i] = 1;       
    } 

    public static void findPrimes(int[] a){

        for(int i = 2; i <a.length; i++){

            if( a[i] == 1){ 
                for (int j = 3*i ; j < a.length; j= j+ i){
                    a[i] = 0; 
                } 
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printPrimes(int[] a){

        for (int i = 2; i < a.length; i++){
            if (a[i] == 1)
                System.out.print(i + ",");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use booleans? The way you are doing it, replacing `int[], 0, 1` with `boolean[], true, false` does the same thing and saves a lot of memory.

Comment: Just a tip: to initialise arrays with the same value in all index, use Array.fill( ) method. In your case, you can use:

`Arrays.fill(a, 2, a.length-1, 1);`

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo: your inner loop should use `a[j] = 0;` instead of `a[i] = 0;`.

(Also, since your array contains 0 or 1 only, it's better to use to use a `bool[]` instead of `int[]`.)

Comment: Thanks so much! It works now, almost perfectly except theres a 4 which isn't a prime number showing up in the list?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in the `findPrimes` method. It loops from `3 * i` instead of `2 * i`, and it uses `a[i]` in the assignment instead of `a[j]`:

```
public static void findPrimes(int[] a) {
  for (int i = 2; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] == 1) { 
      for (int j = 2 * i; j < a.length; j = j + i) {
        a[j] = 0; 
      } 
    }
  }
}
```